# DocusignAPI - How to get & update cusom fields of template through api call

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocusignAPI, trying to get custom fields from the template, update the custom fields dynamically in the c# code before sending to recipient.

Can you please help me which api should I use for this?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I am using following api. (Send an Envelope from a Template). How can I access the template custom fields.                                                                                                https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the **Get Envelope Custom Field Information** API call.  Details of the call can be found in the documentation [here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Custom%20Field%20Information.htm).

URL:  `/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/custom_fields`

Formats:  `XML`, `JSON`

HTTP Method: `GET`

---

Example:

```
GET https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/custom_fields

X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```